# Yii, Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, serialization, yii

I am working on yii+postgresql and I am trying to work with yii-audit-module
but I am facing problem for "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed". 
I used Composer Installation and did all configurations.

Please help me to solve this issue, I got stuck at this point

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you describe the steps to reproduce the problem? Can you show us any code you're trying to run?...

Comment: I am trying to add audit log module to my project for that i am going through this site http://cornernote.github.io/yii-audit-module/

Comment: And at which point in the instructions does the error occur?

Comment: I am unable to debug this, but in /protected/modules/vendor/cornernote/yii-audit-module/audit/AuditModule.php I am not getting homeUrl

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting homeUrl"? I'm not clairvoyant... Again: please put some code into your question that demonstrates the problem, add any error messages you received.

Comment: Thanks for help, but sorry to say really I am not getting any error in console also.

Comment: Again: What do you mean by "not getting homeUrl"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81496/discussion-between-m-gaidhane-and-max-leske).